# Running Two Versions of TeX - Is It Possible?

Tags: miktex, context

I currently am using Tecniccenter with Miktex, and creating conventional LaTeX files. I would like to learn Context. I have read on the contextgarden.net site that it is not advisable to to use Miktex for Context since the Miktex maintainers do not regularly update the Context files, and that the best solution is to install only the  MKIV version of Context. Can I install MKIV to run from the command line while maintaining my Miktex installation? If not, what would be a good, or just workable, solution?

Comment: it is no problem to have the ConTeXt installation together with MikTeX

Answer (score 2):

The [ConTeXt standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone) (also called ConTeXt Suite) is designed in such a way that you can install it in parallel with an existing TeX installation. Simply follow the [instructions](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Windows) on the wiki.

Let's say you install ConTeXt in `C:\Context`. Then, to run context from the command line, you will first have to run

```
C:\Context\tex\setuptex.bat
```

which sets all the environmental variables, etc. Then to compile a file, you can just run

```
context filename
```

Note that you will **not** be able to run MikTex binaries from **that console** but you can run MikTeX binaries from a new console.

Comment: Thank you. That actually answers my next question as well.